# How can I duplicate this simple matlab plot functionality with mathplotlib?

Tags: python, matlab

Here is a simple matlab script to read a csv file, and generate a plot (with which I can zoom in with the mouse as I desire).  I would like to see an example of how this is done in python and mathplotlib.

```
data = csvread('foo.csv');    % read csv data into vector 'data'
figure;                       % create figure
plot (data, 'b');             % plot the data in blue
```

In general, the examples in mathplotlib tutorials I've seen will create a static graph, but it's not interactively "zoomable". Would any python expert care to share an equivalent?

Thanks

Comment: What system are you on that the default backend doesn't allow zoomable figures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr=np.genfromtxt('foo.csv',delimiter=',')
plt.plot(arr[:,0],arr[:,1],'b-')
plt.show()
```

on this data (foo.csv):

```
1,2
2,4
3,9
```

produces

[image]

When you setup the matplotlibrc, one of the key parameters you need to set is the `backend`. Which backend you choose depends on your OS and installation. 
For any typical OS there should be a backend that allows you to pan and zoom the plot interactively. (`GtkAgg` works on Ubuntu). The buttons highlighted in red allow you to pan and zoom, respectively.

Comment: Just what I wanted to get me started! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're familiar with Matlab, I'd suggest using the pylab interface to matplotlib - it mostly mimics Matlab's plotting.  As unutbu says, the zoomability of the plot is determined by the backend you use, a separate issue.

```
from pylab import *
data = genfromtxt("file.csv")
plot(data, 'b')
```